# How to use parameter binding in list view web part

Tags: list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part

We usually use parameter binding in DVWP for eg to get server variables.
Does any body has idea how to do it for xslt list view web part.

I need to fetch looged on user id in list view web part for which I need parameter binding for LOGON_USER.

I have read some where that it can be done using server side object model(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806164.aspx )but I can not do it.

At the max I can use JavaScript object model.

does someone know a,way to do it.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44499/how-to-get-current-user-with-javascript

Comment: I know this is an alternative...What i am looking for specifically for parameter binding. The reason is if i could add parameter binding i will get USER(or any other variable) in XSLT rather that JS.